# How can I build a brick-built monorail track?

Tags: building, monorail, tracks

LEGO haven’t released a new monorail set since the 90s, and the track parts that were made are very expensive and hard to find.

I am interested in building a brick-built alternative. I am particularly inspired by the build shown [here](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/how-many-hours-of-travel-does-it-take-to-wear-out-lego-monorail-tires).

---

## Criteria

#### Vehicle

- 6 to 8 studs wide
- running on rubber tyres
- motor-driven

#### Track Elements

- straight – unlike the original, a central rack is not necessary for level or smooth gradients.
- curved – can be fixed angle or flexible.
- incline – can be fixed angle or flexible.
- track supports
- track switcher (Optional)

#### Parts

- Cannot use existing monorail parts (including the [#2681](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2681&idColor=11#T=C&C=11) and [#2680](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2680&idColor=11#T=C&C=11) supports).
- Avoid rare, expensive parts, or parts out of production.

Comment: Yes, but the motor would be contained in the monorail carriage so it shouldn't affect the track design too much. (Apart from the inclines)

Comment: Great question! I'm excited to see what folks here come up with.

Comment: *so it shouldn't affect the track design too much* – Well, you have to have some cogs or rubber wheels to transmit the force and something that connects them to your motor. The main problem is not designing the track but something that properly can drive on it.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Correct. [This](https://youtu.be/YhpzYhnJONg) is my inspiration for the train, in the sense that the motor and battery box will be contained in one of the carriages.

Comment: What it could have are rubber wheels gripping sideways onto the track (this is just part of an idea so I don't know how the track would be made) and motorised from inside the train. e.g. the wheels stick out the bottom and on flat track are horizontal and quite tight on the sides of the rail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an article about this topic in the November 2018 issue of [HispaBrick magazine](https://www.hispabrickmagazine.com/downloads/).

In addition to a nice interview with the designer (Masao Hidaka), the article shows off some of the techniques used for building the rails:

[image: rail build]

Technically, the design matches most of your specifications.

[image: wheel placement]

It even includes a rather complex motorized switch:

[image: switch]

Here's a complete layout:

[image: complete layout]

I'd definitely encourage you to give the full article a look.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at this youtube channel: [MasaoHidaka](https://www.youtube.com/user/MasaoHidaka) The Track is made up with standard bricks and he managed to create nice curves and even switches. The switches are quite part intensive though.